# The number of 5-digit numbers using $1,2,3,4,5 $

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The number of 5-digit numbers using $1,2,3,4,5$ where each digit is distinct and $1$ should not be in 1st position and $5$ should not be in last position ?

---

I tried like this :

1st position can have $4$ numbers and similarly, last position can have $3$ numbers. Now, Middle 3 elements can be filled in $3,2$ and $1$ respectively.

Total Numbers can be $3*4*3*2*1$ = $72$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is better to consider all arrangements and quit the ones you don't want. There are $5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1=120$ arrangements with the numbers $1,2,3,4,5$.

- Quit the numbers that are with the $1$ in the *first* position. There are $24$ (the other four numbers could be anywhere)
- Quit the numbers that are with the $5$ in the *last* position. There are $24$ (the other four numbers could be anywhere)
- Now notice that I quit twice the numbers that have the $1$ in the first position and the $5$ in the last position, so sum  the numbers that have the $1$ in the first position and the $5$ in the last position, that are $6$.

Now sum them and quit it to $120$:

$$120-48+6=100-22=80-2=78$$

Comment: you need to add $6$ not subtract.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice my mistake.

Comment: For the record, this method of counting is usually called the principle of inclusion and exclusion (or sometimes "the sieve").

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Thanks !! Your approach looks fine.Can you tell me what I am missing with my approach ?

Comment: Maybe (and I say maybe because I'm not totally sure) is the fact that in the middle you could add the $1$ and the $5$ too and your counting doesn't seem to consider that.

Comment: If you like the answer you can put it as the correct ;D